# blenderswap blender objects to threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I'm a newbie to Blender and Blendswap. I downloaded a .blender rendering from blendswap and want to load it into my threejs scene. I exported the blender rendering as a .obj and it downloaded a .obj file as well a .mtl file. I then used the following code trying to import it. There are no error codes but the rendering doesn't show up. I also wanted to see what command is appropriate once this object is imported to set it's position. (x,y,z) I was unable to use .position.set .

```
  var santa;

  var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
        console.log( item, loaded, total );
    };
  var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
    if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
      var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
      console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
    }
  };
  var onError = function ( xhr ) {
    console.log('Error: ' + xhr)
    };

  var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
    loader.load( 'img/santa blendswap.obj', function ( object ) {
      santa = object;
      scene.add( santa );
    }, onProgress, onError );
```

Comment: why were you unable to use position.set?

Comment: Are you sure the obj file is there in the 'img' folder? Also make sure that 'img' folder is in the same path where your html page is located.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work if the obj file is there in the specified path, anyway you can set position of the object after loading it.

```
var santa;
var onProgress = function ( xhr ){
    if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
      var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
      console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
    }
};
var onError = function ( xhr ) {
    console.log('Error: ' + xhr)
};
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
//use %20 to encode space between the file name. 'img/santa blendswap.obj' should also work
loader.load( 'img/santa%20blendswap.obj', function ( object ) {
    santa = object;
    santa.position.set( 0, 5, 10 );//You can set the position like this or use object.position.set( 0, 5, 10 )
    scene.add( santa );
}, onProgress, onError );
```